# Como fazer um select vazio para puxar todos os resultados da coluna

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estou tentando fazer um select vazio, que se não selecionado nenhuma option puxa todos os resultados, usando o AND no SELECT o formulário me obriga a escolher alguma opção, como posso resolver isso? Segue os códigos:

```
<form action="index2.php" method="post" >
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true">

<label for="">Nome:
    <input type="text" name="nome" />
</label>

<label for="">Tipo:
    <select name="tipo" id="">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="P">Personagem</option>
        <option value="R">Reino</option>
        <option value="I">Item</option>
        <option value="A">Ação</option>
    </select>
</label>

<label for="">Vida: 
    <input type="text" name="vida">
</label>

<label for="">Força: 
    <input type="text" name="forca">
</label>

<input type="submit">

</form>
```

--

```
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$tipo = $_POST['tipo'];
$vida = $_POST['vida'];
$forca = $_POST['forca'];
$query = "SELECT * 
FROM WoH 
WHERE NOME LIKE '%".$nome."%' 
AND `TIPO` = '$tipo' 
AND `VD` = '$vida'
";
```

A busca não funciona porque não tem nenhuma linha com valor "" na minha coluna TIPO. Se eu tiro o option vazio, deixando o option personagem como default, ele busca só os personagens, como posso fazer para que de alguma forma quando o usuário quiser pesquisar as cartas em TODOS os tipos, o option default me traga esse resultado?

Comment: Não relacionado com o problema da pergunta (já respondida pelo @JorgeB.), sua query dá oportunidade para SQL Injection. Depois, dê uma espiada nesta questão: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864/

Comment: Tenho a seguinte função nesse arquivo, que não colei aqui.
    function escape($string){
 return htmlentities(trim($string), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}

Isso resolve, não?

Comment: Nao é exatamente o caso, inclusive htmlentities serve pra gerar o display para uso em HTML, e não na base de dados. Por exemplo, o htmlentities converte `<` para `&lt;`, e assim vai. O ideal seria usar binding, conforme descrito no link. Da forma que você fez, até "dá uma disfarçada boa", mas fica um pouco confuso. O mysqli faz isso automático para você, basta usar stmt bind_param: http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode fazer através do PHP dessa forma:

```
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$tipo = $_POST['tipo'];
$vida = $_POST['vida'];
$forca = $_POST['forca'];

$query = "SELECT * 
FROM WoH 
WHERE NOME LIKE '%".$nome."%' AND `VD` = '$vida'";
if($tipo!="")
{
   $query .= " AND `TIPO` = '$tipo'"; //junção sql do tipo no fim da query.
}
```

Comment: Se eu precisar usar esse esquema de valor em branco para puxar tudo com vários input's do tipo texto, seria recomendado utilizar essa mesma forma fazendo vários if's? Tipo o valor de VIDA e FORÇA também preciso que funcione da mesma forma, só considerando se algo for digitado no input.

Comment: Sim, se for como neste caso podes fazer assim mesmo, se só queres usar aquela condição em caso do *input* estar preenchido. Tem é sempre cuidado com os espaços entre condições SQL tanto se a condição do if for satisfeita ou se não for, isso costuma dar algums problemas.

Answer (score 2):

Jamais insira parâmetros POST/GET diretamente na string SQL. Isso permite SQL Injection. Você pode usar mysql_real_escape_string para tratar a string de forma que ela fique segura e então montar a consulta final:

```
$nome = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nome']);
$tipo = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tipo']);
$vida = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['vida']);
$forca = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['forca']);

$query = 'SELECT * FROM WoH '.
         'WHERE NOME LIKE "%'.$nome.'%" '.
         (empty($vida)?'':'AND VD = "'.$vida.'" '.
         (empty($tipo)?'':'AND TIPO = "'.$tipo.'" ';
```

**Atenção**: mysql_real_escape_string foi depreciada no PHP 5.5. A melhor solução é usar prepared statements.